# Can I use SSIS to pull data directly from the Google Analytics API?

Tags: sql, ssis, google-analytics, sql-server-2008-r2, google-analytics-api

Not great at programming so not all that confident of being able to pull data from the Google API.

Basically what I'm trying to do is pull everything from Google Analytics, all data and dump it into a table on a SQL Server (2008 R2). What would be the best way of achieving this?

Would like to automate the process so that it could be scheduled say once a month.

Cheers

Comment: Decompose your problem into manageable chunks. Step 1, get data from Google Analytics. Step 2, add data to SQL Server. Step 3, schedule automated collection of data. As you have tagged SSIS, I would expect the solution to look like Data flow task, Script Transformation as data source, maybe something in between to massage data and an OLE DB Destination to consume the output. Punt that into SQL Server and create a SQL Agent job that runs once a month on schedule you have set.

Comment: Good comment, was thinking of an SSIS package to transfer the data, all steps apart from step 1 I'm comfortable with, the getting the data from Google Analytics

Comment: To refine your problem, I would try restating the question something like "How can I query google analytics using a .NET language?" Which leads me to http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/04/attention-developers-google-analytics.html and https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/ wherein I believe you will want the Core Reporting API. Editing your question might also help deflect the close votes you are receiving.

Answer (score 1):

There an existing add-on specifically for accessing Google Analytics.
Haven't used it but from what I read seems like it will exactly what you are looking for
http://www.google.com/analytics/apps/about?app_id=1325007

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific SSIS DataSource Component for that – https://analyticssource.codeplex.com
It is open source and free.

Comment: This is only for SSIS 2012 and 2014.  The OP specified 2008 R2.